# Labels of same layer overlap each other (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, labeling

I just want the labels of one layer stop overlapping each other, no matter which scale I choose, even if some labels fall outside of my map extend then (only if there A LOT of labels).
Is there still no solution for this?
(Ignore the selected polygons, the labels are mostly for the one in the center of the screenshot)

I think I pretty much tried everything.
Callouts, obstacles, ... nothing worked so far.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please show us the setting you have set for label placement

Comment: I attached 2 more pics.

Comment: In the images, labels don't overlap, but their background rectangles overlap.

Comment: omg...I never saw it that way. I think you're right. So would there be a way to avoid that? With onboard settings?? Likely not. Then I would open up a request for a future qgis update. The placement should definitely take the buffer/frame into account.